# ViewPager поймать событие MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Подскажите как поймать только одно событие при обработке кликов на ViewPager'e.  Например, при листании viewPager'a происходит срабатывание сразу двух событий MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, и сразу же MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. А я хочу отслеживать только события MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, именно клик, а не листание.

**Обновлено.** При клике срабатывает: MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, затем MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. При листании добавляется промежуточное действие MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. Мне не нужно отслеживать листания, то есть как избавиться от MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN при листании?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во-первых не приходят Вам сразу два события, они приходят последовательно - друг за другом.

Пример - пользователь опустил палец на экран, подержал, затем его убрал.

ACTION_DOWN - самое первое событие, которое Вам придёт.

ACTION_MOVE - Высока вероятность, что это событие придёт Вам вторым, а мб даже и третьим-четвёртым... На практике руки у пользователя дрожат (у меня они всегда дрожали достаточно, чтобы поймать его вторым, а после третьей кружки кофе поздней ночью - третьим и даже четвертым).

ACTION_UP - последнее, завершающее событие.

Существуют и другие события, но для примера нам хватило и этих трёх.

Ну а ответ на Ваш вопрос кроется в самом вопросе. Вам нужно ловить только одно событие? Бросьте сачок на пол! Есть старый дедовский способ их фильтрации:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   // В этот блок проходят только события ACTION_DOWN, остальные обойдут его стороной
}
```

Можно даже делать на каждое событие определенное действие:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // действие номер раз только для событий ACTION_DOWN
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // действие номер два только для событий ACTION_MOVE
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // действие номер три только для событий ACTION_UP
        break;
}
```

Вам нужно отслеживать все действия, кроме ACTION_MOVE?

```
if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)  {
    // Ваши действия
}
```

Надо вам ловить конкретно ACTION_DOWN и ACTION_UP, без ACTION_MOVE?

```
int action = event.getAction();
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)  {
    //  действие только для событий ACTION_DOWN и ACTION_UP
}
```

Или так:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // действие только для событий ACTION_DOWN и ACTION_UP
        break;
}
```

Comment: Я проверил все действия, прежде чем задать вопрос) я хочу поймать только одно действие event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, только нажатие, не листание и т.д. Как это сделать? Все что вы написали и так понятно.

Comment: в данный блок попадут действия, которые начнутся с листания, а мне это не нужно! Я ж это написал в вопросе, только клики, а не листания. Если так сделать невозможно - скажите!

Comment: а вы то, что написали сами проверяли? в блок с листаниями (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) попадают касания, потому что выполняется event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: Дело в том, что MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN сработает при листании. А я хочу отслеживать только события именно клика, а не листания. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Честно говоря мне начинает казаться, что вы хотите спросить другой вопрос - "Как не допустить реакции ViewPager на ACTION_MOVE", это так?

Comment: Да, все верно! Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что хотел сделать! Зациклился на нажатии, что забыл про "отжатие".

```
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    moving=false;
                    up=false;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    moving=true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    up=true;
                    break;
            }
            if (up){
                if(moving){
                    Log.e("ACTION_MOVE","ACTION_MOVE");
                }else{
                    Log.e("ACTION_UP","ACTION_UP");
                }
            }
```